# Empty review queues should not shown in the List

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, new-nav

In the drop-down menu for Reviews, empty queues are shown. I think these queues should not be shown, because we can not do something with it and so it makes no sense to see it there.

[image]

Also if I have no daily close votes, queues where I need it will not be shown.

**UPDATE**
If it is a common issue to not remove the item it should also not be removed if I do not have close votes.

Comment: Don't you want to see that a queue is actually empty?! That's a wonderful, magical event. Also, [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/07/01/dont-hide-or-disable-menu-items/).

Comment: @CodyGray I do not want to see thinks that which i can not do anything with it. Also if you refer to the link, the items should also be shown if i do not have any Close votes. So the handling in SQ is not consequent

Comment: @CodyGray What is the help of the Information that the queue is empty?

Comment: @Jens You see that the queue is empty. What help is a missing entry? Is that queue empty? Don't you have enough votes left to use that queue? Don't you have enough reputation to see that queue in the first place? Is this site bugged? A missing entry is too ambiguous.

Comment: @Tom But once has all the situation in common. I can not use the item to do anything. Anyway. But in all this cases the result at this page should be equals. So the items should not be removed in any case.

Answer (score 8):

> What is the help of the Information that the queue is empty?

Showing empty queues is *extremely* useful.

- People might get confused if a queue they use frequently is suddenly gone, wondering whether it has been scrapped or there is something wrong with their device.
- People who happen to see the list for the first time would not get the full picture of what queues exist.
- People who want to check out a specific queue would get confused.

Comment: And why this item is gone when i do not have Close votes? It is also confusable

Comment: @Jens **"And why this item is gone when i do not have Close votes?"** That would be changed. Removing an item from the list is too ambiguous to be helpful.